# Automatic form population in Rails?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, auto-populate

I'm a bit thumped on this one. On my site: www.mystorkparty.com a user creates a large registry for her baby shower. Is there anyway to create and save a populated registry and then let the user can just click auto populate and her registry form has a pre-populated form which she can edit further?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean pre-defined code for a form? In that case, yes you can. Rails was meant to keep repetitive coding at a minimum and you can just create your own .gem file like "myForm.gem" that will generate the proper code for you and route it to a controller giving you the MVC structure.

Comment: Yes, instead of entering each present, brand, color manually there is a predefined one which the user can just edit further. Something simple - automatic. Don't know if a GEM is the answer - doesn't make sense.

Comment: http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/  I think this is basically what you want to do.

Comment: Wouldn't know how to populate a form from that.